# Property 'Template' was not found in type 'FrameworkElement'

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, frameworkelement

Please pardon me for being a complete newbie, but I'm following a tutorial ([Creating a Custom WPF Button Template in XAML](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2007/07/creating-custom-wpf-button-template-in.html)), and I'm running into the error:

> FormatException was thrown due to document error: Property 'Template' was not found in type 'FrameworkElement'.

It seems that the error stems from the following code in XAML:

```
 <Setter Property="Template">
     <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
             <Border Name="border"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Padding="4,2"
                BorderBrush="DarkGray"
                CornerRadius="3"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <Grid >
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="contentShadow"
                    Style="{StaticResource ShadowStyle}">
                    <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform X="1.0" Y="1.0" />
                    </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                </ContentPresenter>
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="content"/>
                </Grid>
        </Border>
```

I've been looking all over for a solution, but haven't found one...this leads me to believe that I'm either overlooking or overthinking something.

What am I missing? Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: See _Download an example XAML file_ in that link for the complete self-contained example.  It shows where the XAML fragment you quote should be inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `FrameworkElement` doesn't have a `Template` property.  The Template is usually defined on a `Control` class.  This is because most WPF elements derive from `FrameworkElement` but they don't all have a Template (`StackPanel`, for example).  Your Setter is probably within a Style (you didn't post that part).  Make sure the `TargetType` of the `Style` is the correct type (most likely Button).

```
<Style x:Key="InformButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Name="border"
                etc...
</Style>
```

Comment: Wow..thanks NotDan! You were spot on. TargetType is what I was missing. And much thanks for explaining!

Comment: I was looking for a shared 'Background' property which also isn't present in `FrameworkElement`. Thanks for pointing out the `Control` class.